# angular firebase build error when try ionic build

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

I got error when I tried to build ionic app.
Actually it wasn't a problem when I build in local, but when I check build status in ionic website, I got a bellow error.

**using**
angular5, ionic3

> typescript: node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts, line: 10 
>               Class 'FirebaseApp' incorrectly implements interface 'FirebaseApp'. Property 
>               'automaticDataCollectionEnabled' is missing in type 'FirebaseApp'.

```
   L9:  export declare const FirebaseAppConfigToken: InjectionToken;
  L10:  export declare class FirebaseApp implements FBApp {
  L11:      name: string;
```

I have no idea. Should I downgrade firebase version?

**UPDATE**

I edited `firebase.app.module.d.ts` like the answer, but I got another error now. I edited `.gitignore` like this.

```
node_modules/*
!node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts
```

> npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.6.0 requires a peer of
>   @firebase/app@^0.1.6 but none was installed.
>
> npm ERR! Invalid tar header. Maybe the tar is corrupted or it needs to
>   be gunzipped?
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/gitlab-runner/.npm/_logs/2018-04-20T07_49_29_110Z-debug.log

Answer (score 5):

I solved with `npm install @firebase/app@0.1.10`.
Error doesn't happen and build success.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem adding this line:

automaticDataCollectionEnabled: boolean;

on the file:

node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts

Final result:

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseAppConfig } from './';
import { FirebaseApp as FBApp } from '@firebase/app-types';
import { FirebaseAuth } from '@firebase/auth-types';
import { FirebaseDatabase } from '@firebase/database-types';
import { FirebaseMessaging } from '@firebase/messaging-types';
import { FirebaseStorage } from '@firebase/storage-types';
import { FirebaseFirestore } from '@firebase/firestore-types';
export declare const FirebaseAppConfigToken: InjectionToken<FirebaseAppConfig>;
export declare class FirebaseApp implements FBApp {
    name: string;
    options: {};
    automaticDataCollectionEnabled: boolean; // missing line
    auth: () => FirebaseAuth;
    database: () => FirebaseDatabase;
    messaging: () => FirebaseMessaging;
    storage: () => FirebaseStorage;
    delete: () => Promise<any>;
    firestore: () => FirebaseFirestore;
}
export declare function _firebaseAppFactory(config: FirebaseAppConfig, appName?: string): FirebaseApp;
```

Comment: I've already done like that, but the problem is when I edit this `firebase.app.module.d.ts` file, because I work with ionic pro and it execute automatically `npm install`. So even though I edit, it go back to before.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the property *automaticDataCollectionEnabled* to the *FirebaseApp* class (node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts).

```
export declare class FirebaseApp implements FBApp {
   name: string;
   options: {};
   automaticDataCollectionEnabled: boolean; // add it like this
   auth: () => FirebaseAuth;
   database: () => FirebaseDatabase;
   messaging: () => FirebaseMessaging;
   storage: () => FirebaseStorage;
   delete: () => Promise<any>;
   firestore: () => FirebaseFirestore;
}
```

Comment: Should I edit the file, firebase.app.module.d.ts? Cause it’s not what I made.

Comment: Ofring,  I edited exactly like that, but I got another error.

npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.6.0 requires a peer of @firebase/app@^0.1.6 but none was installed.

npm ERR! Invalid tar header. Maybe the tar is corrupted or it needs to be gunzipped?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/gitlab-runner/.npm/_logs/2018-04-20T07_49_29_110Z-debug.log

Comment: I actually changed like that and add to git but still same error occurs.

Comment: Is there a work around because this doesn't fix it for our CI since we are editing the node_modules. What is the last working version?

Answer (score 0):

```
 npm i @firebase/app@^0.1.6
```

This worked for me. As the warning says, firebase/app needs to be installed separately. Did the same and my project compiled successfully.